# limit click button in html

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to limit a button that can be clicked only 5 times to add radio button. After 5 times adding radio button, it will be disabled. What is the javascript code for this matter? I only able to disable it once after it is clicked. Below is the code

html

```
<input type ='button' id="id" onClick="a();">
        <div id='a'></div>
```

javascript

```
function a(){
    document.getElementById('a').innerHTML += "<input type='radio'>";
    document.getElementById("id").disabled=true;
}
```

Comment: Can you use jquery or only plain javascript?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Place a global counter and play with it

```
var counter=0;

function a(){
if(counter<5){
    document.getElementById('a').innerHTML += "<input type='radio'>";
    counter++;
}
else{
    document.getElementById("id").disabled=true;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A global variable for amount of times clicked will work:

```
var clicked = 0;
function a(){
    document.getElementById('a').innerHTML += "<input type='radio'>";
    clicked++; //increment

    if (clicked == 5)
        document.getElementById("id").disabled=true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need:

```
var counter = 0;

function a ()
{
    if (counter++ < 5)
        document.getElementById('a').innerHTML += "<input type='radio'>";
    else
        document.getElementById('id').disabled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var counter = 1;

function a(){
    if(counter >= 5) {
        document.getElementById("id").disabled=true;
        return false;
    }
    document.getElementById('a').innerHTML += "<input type='radio'>";

    counter++
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can count the radio buttons

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset= "utf-8">
<title>Add 5</title>
<style>
input[disabled]{text-decoration:line-through;color:white;}    
</style>
<script>

function add5(){
    var radio, 
    btn= document.getElementById('add_radio'),
    pa= document.getElementById('radioDiv'), 
    R= pa.querySelectorAll('[type=radio]');

    if(R.length<5){
        radio= document.createElement('input');
        radio.type='radio'; 
        pa.appendChild(radio);
    }
    else btn.disabled= 'disabled';
}
</script>

</head>
<body>    
<p>
<input type ='button' id="add_radio" value="Add Radio"onClick="add5();">
</p>
<div id='radioDiv'></div>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```