# Limit number of clicks on button

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am trying to make a website where you can comment on posts, and one of the commenting features is that you can like/dislike comments. I know how to insert the votes into a MySQL database, but I want to limit the votes to 1 per user *forever*. I suppose that you can't do this with PHP, so I guess the only answer is using JS.

P.S: *I know that there are many questions out there that are similar to mine, e.g., [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19841632/limit-click-button-in-html/19841671), or [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323948/disabling-the-button-after-once-click), but none of them answer my question. As I said before, I want to limit the clicks forever, but in those questions, the clicks are limited only for the moment. So please, don't take my question for a duplicate.*

Comment: Php is the right choice. Just echo button if user has not voted already. If you implement js only, it can be hacked to remove limitation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well this is a theoretical question so I would be only able to give theoretical answer without any code. You may create another table in database where user id is primary key and store all clicks user has done. Once you fetch user information fetch this information as well and then put check in buttons using js to disable button or not if not commented / voted.
If user has not commented / voted and once user does that you can immediately disable the button and save it to MYSQL database.

Comment: I will try that

Comment: you may assign buttons id and save that id as column name, so it would be easy to fetch and update

Comment: Inserting and limiting votes worked alright, but now I am having trouble displaying all the votes besides the voting button. Any suggestions?

Comment: I cannot help unless I see the code. It might be a logical error

Comment: What I mean is this: `while($r = msyqli_fetch_array(msqyli_query("SELECT * FROM likes WHERE user='$username' AND page='http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]'"))) {                         
       echo $r['num_votes'];                                                                                                                                     }` But it echoes 111111111111111111111

Comment: Never mind, I already got the answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23202649/sum-of-column-in-using-mysqli-and-php) link

Answer (score 0):

You can't limit voting with the only Javascript. Because the code will be on the client-side and some people could bypass this limitation.

So you steps will be:
1 Frontend: You could limit in the client-side, as stated in the links you mentioned.
2 Backend: You store (insert) votes to the database
3 Backend: Before storing (2), you should check if the user voted already (select from the database). If voted, do not store vote (2).